# PNG Error when exporting Jar for OSX

Tags: java, macos, png, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL, and Slick to load in my Images. I exported my jar and created a fat jar using JarSplice with the dependencies for Windows and OSX. The jar runs perfectly on windows however on OSX I am getting the following error referring to my PNG assets.

```
java.io.IOException: unsupported interlace method
 at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData.readIHDR(PNGImageData.java:398)
 at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData.init(PNGImageData.java:106)
 at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData.loadImage(PNGImageData.java:680)
 at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:62)
 at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:43)
 at     org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:277)
 at     org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:231)
 at     org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:171)
 at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:196)
 at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:170)
 at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:158)
 at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:136)
 at com.danielmessias.spaceshooter.SpaceShooter.loadImages(SpaceShooter.java:137)
 at com.danielmessias.spaceshooter.SpaceShooter.start(SpaceShooter.java:131)
 at com.danielmessias.spaceshooter.SpaceShooter.main(SpaceShooter.java:81)
```

I've resaved all my assets and re-exported without interlacing, so I don't know what the problem is.

All help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Some of your PNG images were probably saved in interlaced format. Recheck that. ref: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Game/foogamelib/org/newdawn/slick/opengl/PNGImageData.java.htm

Comment: I resaved all my images without interlacing, I use photoshop so it's easy to ensure they are not, and still the error persists

Comment: I have the same issue... :l Anybody has a solution?